# Moodle: Scheduled tasks set for one minute sets itself to ASAP, but never reruns

Tags: moodle

I have been monitoring the Complete learning plans which are due task, which is set to run every minute. I have set the cron.php script with a password to force the cron job to run. When I reload the page I notice that the cron job runs, sets the next run date time, but doesn't run again and changes to ASAP.

I am using Moodle 3.6.3 on Windows IIS.

Comment: Have you created a task in task scheduler for this page?

Comment: @MeetuU What do you mean? Create a task to open that page every minute?

Comment: Yes. I did the same and it's working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a task in task scheduler to execute the script after every minute (or any time you want). Use "Start a program" action. Replace "C:\Program Files\PHP\v7.2\php-win.exe" with your php version and also change the moodle path to yours.

[image]